# Is it possible to stack either formset_factory, inlineformset_factory - Django

Tags: python, django, forms, formset

As the question says, i haven't found any info about stacking either formset_factory, inlineformset_factory into either formset_factory, inlineformset_factory

maybe someone in here might know something about it? :o